# Rest API attributes conditional rendering and replacement of string in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to get the data from rest API in react and I am getting the data successfully using the Axios. The attributes i am getting from the rest API are uniqueName, Title & documentType . The last attribute "documentType" value is either "invoice" or "requisition" .

Well only for the last attribute the requirement is, if the value of the documentType is "invoice" so print a message that "It's invoice" or if the value is requisition, print the message that "It's  Requistion. I am new to react and I don't know how to apply if condition in the render method.
Here is my code.

> 

```
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.errorMessage && (
      <h3 className="error">{this.state.errorMessage}</h3>
    )}
    <ul>
      {records.map((record, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          Requisition : {record.uniqueName} - Title : {record.Title} 

          if ({record.documentType == 'requisition'}) {
                <h1>It's Requisition</h1>
              }
              else
              {
                <h1>It's Invoice</h1>
             }
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
)
```

Thanks everyone :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conditional operator inside of `{` `}`s:

```
return (
    <div>
        {this.state.errorMessage && (
            <h3 className="error">{this.state.errorMessage}</h3>
        )}
        <ul>
            {records.map((record, index) => (
                <li key={index}>
                    Requisition : {record.uniqueName} - Title : {record.Title}
                    {
                        record.documentType == 'requisition'
                            ? <h1>It's Requisition</h1>
                            : <h1>It's Invoice</h1>
                    }
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: I have no words to thank you. It's working. Thanks heaps dude.